# Can I use while or cursor in T-SQL to insert into new table

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I wrote a query to get the total of each date for the personID what I want to do is to insert the results into a new table using stored procedure my query is something like that for reference (using AdventureWorks2019)

```
WITH TOP7 AS
(
    SELECT 
        SOH.SalesPersonID, SOH.OrderDate,
        SUM(SOH.TotalDue) AS Total,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SOH.SalesPersonID ORDER BY SOH.OrderDate DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH
    LEFT JOIN 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH2 ON SOH.SalesOrderID = SOH2.SalesOrderID
    WHERE 
        SOH.SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY
        SOH.OrderDate, SOH.SalesPersonID
)
(
SELECT SalesPersonID, OrderDate, Total, RowNum
FROM TOP7
WHERE RowNum <= 7
)
```

This is the output I get:

```
ID    Date                        Total      RowNum
----------------------------------------------------
274   2014-05-01 00:00:00.000    42546.9235   1
274   2014-03-31 00:00:00.000   110623.7157   2
274   2014-03-01 00:00:00.000    46525.3068   3
274   2014-01-29 00:00:00.000     1592.5736   4
274   2013-11-30 00:00:00.000    79835.0276   5
274   2013-09-30 00:00:00.000   102227.2339   6
274   2013-08-30 00:00:00.000      2194.914   7
275   2014-05-01 00:00:00.000    417208.4727  1
275   2014-03-31 00:00:00.000    273730.5071  2
275   2014-03-01 00:00:00.000    221438.2289  3
275   2014-01-29 00:00:00.000    279451.2658  4
```

What I want to do is to insert the results into a new table something like that

```
ID, Fdate, Ftotal, Sdate, Stotal, Tdate, Ttotal, Fdate, Ftotal, Fidate, Fitotal, Sidate, Sitotal, Sedate, Stotal

274 | 2014-05-01 | 42546.9235 | 2014-03-31 | 110623.7157 | 2014-03-01 | 46525.3068  | 2014-01-29 | 1592.5736 | 2013-11-30 | 79835.0276   | 2013-09-30 | 102227.2339 | 2013-08-30 | 2194.914
```

I'm using SQL Server.

I want to do that for all Id's that I have in the results - how can I achieve that?

Thank you in advance

Edit :

I did this to insert into the new table

```
WITH TOP7 AS
(
    SELECT 
        SOH.SalesPersonID, SOH.OrderDate,
        SUM(SOH.TotalDue) AS Total,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SOH.SalesPersonID ORDER BY SOH.OrderDate DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH
    LEFT JOIN 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH2 ON SOH.SalesOrderID = SOH2.SalesOrderID
    WHERE 
        SOH.SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY
        SOH.OrderDate, SOH.SalesPersonID
)
    INSERT INTO [Person].[WeekEmployeeTotals] ([PersonID]
      ,[FirstDate]
      ,[FirstDateTotal]
      ,[SecondDate]
      ,[SecondDateTotal]
      ,[ThirdDate]
      ,[ThirdDateTotal]
      ,[FourthDate]
      ,[FourthDateTotal]
      ,[FifthDate]
      ,[FifthDateTotal]
      ,[SixthDate]
      ,[SixthDateTotal]
      ,[SeventhDate]
      ,[SeventhDateTotal])
SELECT  SalesPersonID, 
        Date1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total1 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN Total END),
        Date2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total2 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN Total END),
        Date3 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total3 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN Total END),
        Date4 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 4 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total4 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 4 THEN Total END),
        Date5 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 5 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total5 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 5 THEN Total END),
        Date6 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 6 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total6 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 6 THEN Total END),
        Date7 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 7 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total7 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 7 THEN Total END)

FROM    TOP7
WHERE   RowNum <= 7
GROUP BY SalesPersonID;
```

but I have a question how can I set the Select to insert i mean something like that

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertFromSHO]
    @PID INT,
    @D1 datetime,
    @T1 numeric(24,7),
    @D2 datetime,
    @T2 numeric(24,7),
    @D3 datetime,
    @T3 numeric(24,7),
    @D4 datetime,
    @T4 numeric(24,7),
    @D5 datetime,
    @T5 numeric(24,7),
    @D6 datetime,
    @T6 numeric(24,7),
    @D7 datetime,
    @T7 numeric(24,7)

AS
    SET @D1 = (SELECT Date1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN OrderDate END) FROM TOP7 WHERE RowNum <= 7)
```

^
I know this is wrong but this is what i'm trying to do because I need to do that a lot in the future so I need to know a good method to achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the results in the output you want by using conditional aggregation

```
WITH TOP7 AS
(
    SELECT 
        SOH.SalesPersonID, SOH.OrderDate,
        SUM(SOH.TotalDue) AS Total,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SOH.SalesPersonID ORDER BY SOH.OrderDate DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH
    LEFT JOIN 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH2 ON SOH.SalesOrderID = SOH2.SalesOrderID
    WHERE 
        SOH.SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY
        SOH.OrderDate, SOH.SalesPersonID
)
SELECT  SalesPersonID, 
        Date1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total1 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN Total END),
        Date2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total2 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN Total END),
        Date3 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total3 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN Total END),
        Date4 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 4 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total4 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 4 THEN Total END),
        Date5 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 5 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total5 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 5 THEN Total END),
        Date6 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 6 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total6 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 6 THEN Total END),
        Date7 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 7 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total7 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 7 THEN Total END)
FROM    TOP7
WHERE   RowNum <= 7
GROUP BY SalesPersonID;
```

**[Example on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=25c91b08c5fcf5a2b282c8e46a4c7e88)**

It is probably not a great idea to store the data in this format though, if you need frequent access to the data in this format it would be better to create a view. I've also removed your join here, as it seems completely pointless as you never reference `SOH2`:

```
CREATE VIEW Top7SalesPivot
AS
WITH TOP7 AS
(
    SELECT 
        SOH.SalesPersonID, 
        SOH.OrderDate,
        SUM(SOH.TotalDue) AS Total,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SOH.SalesPersonID ORDER BY SOH.OrderDate DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH
    WHERE 
        SOH.SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY
        SOH.OrderDate, SOH.SalesPersonID
)
SELECT  SalesPersonID, 
        Date1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total1 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN Total END),
        Date2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total2 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN Total END),
        Date3 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total3 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN Total END),
        Date4 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 4 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total4 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 4 THEN Total END),
        Date5 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 5 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total5 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 5 THEN Total END),
        Date6 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 6 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total6 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 6 THEN Total END),
        Date7 = MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 7 THEN OrderDate END),
        Total7 = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum = 7 THEN Total END)
FROM    TOP7
WHERE   RowNum <= 7
GROUP BY SalesPersonID;
```

This way you don't need to update your table each time a sale is added.

If this is not performing well, then you may find that the following index helps:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Sales_SalesOrderHeader__SalesPersonID_OrderDate 
    ON Sales.SalesOrderHeader (SalesPersonID, OrderDate) 
    INCLUDE (TotalDue);
```

Comment: Thank you very much that solved the problem for me, but is this method good for big records ?

Comment: As long as you have the right indexes (I've added an example to the question), then there is no reason this would not scale well. How big are you talking?

Comment: I'm still new to SQL i'm working on small and medium size tables for now, so i'm trying more ways for the same result to get the best possible solution for the work, that's why i'm asking. Thank you again :D

Comment: As a rule of thumb, I would always at least try and use views over snapshot tables, as the cost of maintaining these tables, or the problems caused by them being out of date usually outweigh the benefits. If you subsequently find performance issues, then I would look to see what index might help. If that didn't work, I would then try and use an indexed view (as SQL Server maintains that for you), only as a last resort would I use snapshot tables.

Comment: There are other factors too, such as read/write ratio. If you need this data for a report that is run once a day, but you add hundreds of sales a day, then updating the table for each sale is going to be significantly more overhead than running the query once when you need it. If however, you run the report 100s of times a day, but only add one sale, then the snapshot may be a better option. Other's may have different opinions, but this is what I do based on my experience. I typically don't work with huge data (tables < 100m records), but I work with big enough data to have seen these issues.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and your help @GarethD but can you help me in this one? i edited the question.
  Thank you in advance

Comment: If you have a new question,then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), don't edit an existing one. What you are doing is a really bad idea, unless you have a very good reason to, you should keep your data normalised. Why would you want to store something in 7 columns, when 7 rows is just as good, and adheres to [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form#:~:text=Third%20normal%20form%20(3NF)%20is,in%201971%20by%20Edgar%20F.)

Answer (score 0):

No need for a cursor for this. SQL is a set-based language, in which such operation is easy to perform without loops. You can just use the `insert ... select` syntax:

```
WITH TOP7 AS (
    SELECT 
        SOH.SalesPersonID, SOH.OrderDate,
        SUM(SOH.TotalDue) AS Total,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SOH.SalesPersonID ORDER BY SOH.OrderDate DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH
    LEFT JOIN 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH2 ON SOH.SalesOrderID = SOH2.SalesOrderID
    WHERE 
        SOH.SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY
)
INSERT INTO mytable(ID, Fdate, Ftotal, Sdate, Stotal, Tdate, Ttotal, Fdate, Ftotal, Fidate, Fitotal, Sidate, Sitotal, Sedate, Stotal)
SELECT SalesPersonID, OrderDate, Total, RowNum
FROM TOP7
WHERE RowNum <= 7
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I tried that before and didn't work for me, one of the Errors i got is


(The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.)



because i need row numbers from 1 to 7 for each PersonId to be inserted for each entry in the new table that's why i need loops (I guess)